# Cron not executing Shell Script on Ubuntu

Tags: cron

I have a remote `.sh` script to take backup of mySQL file. Cron is running by .sh file not executing. Content of Crontab are:

```
#SHELL=/bin/bash PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin 
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/dscript/db_backup.sh > /tmp/db.output
```

File Contents are:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)

zipname="db_prod_$DATE.sql"
mysqldump db_prod > $zipname
aws s3 mv $zipname s3://mybackups/$zipname
rm -rf $zipname

zipname="db_staging_$DATE.sql"
mysqldump db_staging > $zipname
aws s3 mv $zipname s3://mybackups/$zipname
rm -rf $zipname
```

**Bash path**

```
bash: /bin/bash /etc/bash.bashrc /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
```

I am on Ubuntu.

File is is in `+x` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)
zipname="db_prod_$DATE.sql"
SCRIPT_LOG_FILE="/tmp/backup.log"

echo "[${DATE}] [INFO] Starting personnal backup" > ${SCRIPT_LOG_FILE}
$(which mysqldump) db_prod > $zipname
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ] && [ -f ${zipname} ];then
    echo "[$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)] [INFO] Mysqldump save file ${zipname}" > ${SCRIPT_LOG_FILE}
    # file is created continue job with this file ...
    $(which aws) s3 mv $zipname s3://mybackups/$zipname
    rm -rf $zipname
else
    echo "[$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)] [ERROR] Mysqldump can't save file ${zipname}" > ${SCRIPT_LOG_FILE} 
fi
exit 0
```

And **crontab -l** must be:

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/dscript/db_backup.sh &> /tmp/error.and.result.db.output
```

Answer (score 0):

**check cron error:**
try to see error with:

```
~$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog|grep CRON|grep db_backup.sh
~$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog|grep CRON|grep MY_USERNAME
```

(Permission denied or other)

*where MY_USERNAME is the user execute : **crontab -e***

**check script error:**

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/dscript/db_backup.sh > /tmp/result.db.output
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/dscript/db_backup.sh 2> /tmp/error.db.output
```

or simply

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/dscript/db_backup.sh &> /tmp/error.and.result.db.output
```

The question is whether the error comes from the execution of cron or is in the script, the above methods will help you find the source of the problem.

Comment: output file is created but blank. The above command produced following:

**CRON[29315]: (ubuntu) CMD (/home/ubuntu/deployment_scripts/db_backup.sh > /tmp/db.output)**

Comment: excuse me , have you really try: 
 
&> /tmp/error.and.result.db.output

Comment: empty output is normal in your case, put an echo in your file: echo "script start"

Comment: Yes.. now I got it.. it says:

**/home/ubuntu/dscript/db_backup.sh: line 7: aws: command not found
/home/ubuntu/dscript/db_backup.sh: line 12: aws: command not found**